# Migrating off TFS to Bitbucket

Tags: tfs, bitbucket-server

We are migrating source code off TFS to Bitbucket.  Can this be done directly?

Have not attempted to migrate any source code yet.

Comment: What version of TFS? Are you targeting Git or TFVC?

Comment: TFS 2012.  The management team chose Bitbucket as the new source code repository.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a tool like [`git-tfs`](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) to convert the TFVC changesets to Git commits. It works relatively well, but if you have a significant amount of history it's going to be slow. And if you've done weird things with branches, it may not cover every base. I've used it many times with varying degrees of success.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct import currently available on BitBucket to import repositories from a TFS server.

As Daniel already pointed out, what you will need to do is bridge your TFS repositories from TFVC to Git (with [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)
) and then push those new Git repositories to BitBucket.

I would like to share some useful tutorial to help you do this step by step.

1. A blog for your reference: [Migrate a TFS Branch to a Bitbucket
   (Git) Repository](http://www.adrianbrown.id.au/Migrate-TFS-Branch-to-Bitbucket-Git/)
2. Once you've migrated from TFVC to Git, you will easily be able to
   [import your Git repositories into Bitbucket Server](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html).

You could also take a look at BitBucket's official support link about this topic: [Bitbucket: Migrating from TFS to Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/confeval/development-tools-evaluator-resources/bitbucket/bitbucket-migrating-from-tfs-to-bitbucket)

Finally, if you want to do it all at once, you choose to make a batch file that does all the steps for each project that you have.